# What happened to the first actor to play Dan?

Tags: character, casting, lucifer

On  the TV show [Lucifer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4052886/), why was the role of Chloe's ex husband recast?

In the pilot he was played by a different actor to the full series. The new actor is shown [in this picture](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1204760/).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There's only ever been one actor, *Kevin Alejandro*, whose picture you linked to?

Comment: There was a different actor in the pilot; I didn't even notice until I looked it up.

Comment: Oh, just saw that myself. That's not hugely unusual, pilots often change actors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're asking about the fact that Nicholas Gonzalez played Dan in the pilot episode, while Kevin Alejandro has played him ever since.

That's not unusual. Pilot episodes are usually filmed well in advance of the rest of the series, and studios make numerous changes (tone, characters, etc.) as part of the deal to get them picked up to series.

In this case, no explanation was given *why* the role was re-cast, but it was announced last summer that the cast change had happened, e.g. [here](http://deadline.com/2015/07/kevin-alejandro-cast-lucifer-fox-recasting-1201466834/). Deadline does note that Alejandro "recently became available", so perhaps the studio just thought he fit better; perhaps test audiences didn't like Gonzalez or he didn't play well against Lauren German. We'll probably never know.

Answer (score 6):

[We got this covered says](http://wegotthiscovered.com/tv/kevin-alejandro-fox-lucifer/):

> No reason for Gonzalez’s exit was given, and it sounds like his part
>   in the pilot will remain intact despite the role swap.

[Deadline notes](http://deadline.com/2015/07/kevin-alejandro-cast-lucifer-fox-recasting-1201466834/):

> Alejandro, repped by Gersh, Main Title and Hansen Jacobson, just
>   recently became available, coming off the A&E drama *The Returned*. He
>   previously was a regular on *True Blood*, *Southland* and *Golden Boy*.